# use a custom directory for build in eclipse cdt c++ makefile project

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

hi i have a c++ makefile project in eclipse helios cdt.

my external makefile make the binary output files in projectdirectory/bin 
if i build project eclipse runs the makefile and there are no compilation problem but if i run it.. eclipse doesn't find the files..

some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you goto the "Run" menu and select "Debug Configurations" or "Run Configurations" (whichever concerns you), select "C/C++ Application", and then press the 'New' icon which is a little white page with a yellow plus icon in the top right.

On the right hand side you should see a text field "C/C++ Application:" with the buttons "Search Project..." and "Browse...". Select "Browse..." and navigate to the location of the build output executable.

This should be sufficient to get you up and running.

Comment: ok perfect, thanks. BUT in the makefile there are some weird path to ".so" files like "../../lib/libfmodex.so". in shell i need do write: "cd bin" to run correctly. if i run in eclipse i get some: "error while loading shared libraries"

Comment: "so" files are like "dll" files from windows and need to be available to the executable when it runs (by being searchable in a link library path), in this case fmodex is a multiplatform audio library. On linux you have special directory "/lib" where such libraries are typically installed.

Comment: Now consider the path you mention: "../../lib/libfmodex.so", depending on where you have located your workspace, the makefile will be sending the shared library to that relative location. I would double check this actually ends up in your "/lib" directory, or alternatively you can goto the "Environment" tab in the debug or run configuration (that I explained how to get to in my answer) and add a new variable entry "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" and set the value to the directory location of the "libfmodex.so" file.